# Vertexes get slightly offset when extruding or moving an object

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

In a model I am working on, I have begun to notice a slight offset to the objects' points when trying to move (using "g") or extrude (using "e") an object (see photos below): it is not caused by any movement of the mouse.

This problem seems to be isolated to only the scene that I am currently working on.

[image]

Comment: could you share the object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/